# Check for item of multiple object arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Assuming this is my array data

```
[
  { target: ['foo', 'bar'] },
  { target: [] }
]
```

I need to check if there is minimum of one item for any target array. So in the above example the result should be `true`.

For this, the result is `false`:

```
[
  { target: [] },
  { target: [] }
]
```

I'm not quite sure how to face this. So I think I have merge all target elements into one array and check if there is an empty array or not.

If this is the correct way, I just need a hint how to merge all arrays into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check the length property of `target` property.

```js
var array = [{ target: ['foo', 'bar'] }, { target: [] }];

console.log(array.some(({ target }) => target.length));
```